# Adding a title for Wordpress Navigation

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have the following code displaying navigation on my Wordpress site;

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
'container' => false, 
'theme_location' => 'primary', 
'menu' => 'mainmenu',
'menu_id' => 'access'
) ); 
?>
```

How would I make it so the navigation displays a title for each link generated? This is for SEO purposes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just add the title in post and page which you used for menu it will automatically display the title.

Comment: @Praveenkalal

No good, unfortunately. It's been poorly coded. Very poorly coded. Thanks for the input though, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

you need a custom walker function to achieve this. This could help you: http://shinraholdings.com/62/custom-nav-menu-walker-function/#example-code